# AWS cloudformation bind domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am setting up a EC2 server using a custom cloudformation template. I need to set the following things for the server

- domain name
- server hostname
- server id

which properties do I need to use?

Comment: You can manage the domain name from cloudformation using a Route53  and an Elastic IP resource. Setting the server hostname and server id will depend on the operating system of your server.  By server id, do you mean AWS instance-id? or the internal machine name? You can't set the AWS instance-id.

Comment: Thanks for the info, server id is a internal property we use for identifying the server

Answer (score 0):

Domain name would be defined under the AWS::Route53::HostedZone resource. Server Hostname via UserData (depending on your OS) and if you're looking to set server id you could do so using Tags.